# why does stripos evaluates to false

Tags: php, stripos

I have a string `$x = 'hello world.'`. I want to see if $x contains string `$y = 'hello'`.

If i do

```
stripos($x, $y);
```

it returns a numeric 0, the index where string $y starts.  However this evaluates to FALSE.  How can I evaluate this so it returns true?

Comment: refer this : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp
if you do this : `echo strpos("hello world, hello","l"); you will get position : 2`

Comment: Please make sure that your search string should be case sensitive.

Comment: how are u comparing, try to use "===" for comparing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the warning notice from [manual](http://php.net/stripos):

> **Warning:** This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the `===` operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

So you should use like this:

```
if(stripos($x, $y) !== FALSE)
// Found
else
// Not found
```

For reference see [this example](http://php.net/stripos#example-5487) from manual.

Comment: thank you.  I did read that and try it.  Does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: I doubt the problem might be because you are using `i` - __case-insensitive__. If you need not, use `strpos` instead

Comment: @user3738926 Explain "does not seem to work." This *is* how the function works, as explained in the docs. You must test for falsity using `===` or `!==`, as (very correctly) explained in this answer.

Comment: @user3738926 Well fine! Mark it accepted, if it did so for you!

Comment: Well fine! I will.

Answer (score 0):

if you use this it will be return true

```
 !(stripos($x, $y)); 


$x = 'hello world.';
$y = 'hello';
echo !(stripos($x, $y));
```